# Добавить элемент в массив без индекса

Tags: php, массивы

Здравствуйте.

Как добавить элемент в массив php без индекса?

```
<?php
$array = array();
array_push($array, array("cid"=> 1, "title"=> 2));
//, == $array[] = array("cid"=> 1, "title"=> 2);
?>
```

выводит

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cid] => 1
            [title] => 0
        )
)
```

нужно

```
Array
(
    Array
        (
            [cid] => 1
            [title] => 0
        )
)
```

т.е. без индекса

Comment: Во первых, в массиве должен быть индекс или ключ, по которому элемент может быть найден или идентифицирован. Во-вторых, если Вы опишете, что нужно сделать в конечном итоге, то может народ подскажет решение.

Comment: @zhenyab в конечном итоге............

Comment: @ikerya  а как вы потом собираетесь обращаться к элементу массива, у которого нет ключа (идентификатора), по которому нужно доставать этот самый элемент?

Comment: просто я получал его без индекса вот так:  `{"response": {["cid": 1, "title": "test"], ["cid": 2, "title": test2]}}`, а нужно было пару элементов добавить в начало масива и выходило вот так: `{"response": 0: {["cid": 3, "title": "test3]}, {["cid": 1, "title": "test"], ["cid": 2, "title": test2]}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы получаете ответ в формате JSON.

Используйте встроенную функцию [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) для преобразования вашего массива.

```
$array = [
    'response' => [
        [
            'cid'   => 1,
            'title' => 'test'
        ],
        [
            'cid' => 2,
            'title' => 'test2'
        ]
    ]
];
echo json_encode($array); // {"response":[{"cid":1,"title":"test"},{"cid":2,"title":"test2"}]}
```

Попробуем в массив response добавить элемент, чтобы он был таким же, как предыдущие два:

```
$array['response'][] = [
    'cid' => 3,
    'title' => 'test3'
];

echo json_encode($array);
//{"response":[{"cid":1,"title":"test"},{"cid":2,"title":"test2"},{"cid":3,"title":"test3"}]}
```

Comment: я это знаю) попробуйте в массив response добавить элемент, чтобы он был таким же, как предыдущие два

Comment: Добавил в ответ, если я правильно понял.

Comment: не получалось у меня так, а тут получилось спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад помочь )

Answer (score 5):

Без индекса элемент не может быть добавлен в массив. Но вы можете всегда назначить свой индекс будь то числовой или текстовый.

Comment: просто я получал его без индекса вот так:  `{"response": {["cid": 1, "title": "test"], ["cid": 2, "title": test2]}}`, а нужно было пару элементов добавить в начало масива и выходило вот так: `{"response": 0: {["cid": 3, "title": "test3]}, {["cid": 1, "title": "test"], ["cid": 2, "title": test2]}}`

Comment: В том, что Вы написали, хоть и с ошибкой, но индексы присутствуют. В массиве верхнего уровня индексом является текстовая метка "response". После добавления элемента в начало массива, добавляется числовой индекс 0. И в результате ваш массив выглядит: `{0: {"cid": 3, ...}, "response": {"cid": 1, ...}}`